# Collapse DT table columns by default

Tags: r, dt

As per below the documentation (https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html),
the below code should collapse first and second columns by default(0,1), but when tried it is displaying all columns by default.

Can we have only 2 columns displayed by default?

```
datatable(
        iris2, rownames = FALSE,
        extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
          dom = 'Bfrtip',
          buttons = list(list(extend = 'colvis', columns = c(2, 3, 4)))
        )
      )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to hide the columns with `columnDefs`:

```
datatable(
  iris, rownames = FALSE,
  extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = list(list(extend = 'colvis', columns = c(2, 3, 4))),
    columnDefs = list(
      list(targets = c(2,3,4), visible = FALSE)
    )
  )
)
```

---

## EDIT

In your comments, you ask for a "Show all" feature (you should have opened a new question, but well). Here is the way I found:

```
datatable(
  iris, rownames = FALSE,
  extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = list(
      list(
        extend = 'colvis', 
        columns = c(2, 3, 4)
      ),
      list(
        extend = 'colvisGroup', 
        text = "Show all",
        show = ":hidden"
      ),
      list(
        extend = 'colvisGroup', 
        text = "Show none",
        hide = ":visible"
      )
    ),
    columnDefs = list(
      list(targets = c(2,3,4), visible = FALSE)
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Awesome . Last clarification, Can we add another feature to dropdown where we have "ALL", so that when user selects "ALL" , all hidden columns are displayed at once

Comment: Hi @Stephane, Did you get a chance to see if this is possible :)

Comment: @manishp See my edit. But this does not add the "Show all" button in the dropdown, this creates another button.

Comment: I got this working. But when I download(csv) the DT table, it downloads all columns . Can we make it specific? (Like what ever columns are displayed, only those to be downloaded)

Comment: @manishp Add this button settings: `list(extend = "excel", exportOptions = list(columns = ":visible"))`.

Comment: Is it not possible to have both Collapse and expand in same button?

Comment: @manishp I think it's doable. But please open a new question. It's not convenient to give an answer as a comment, and it's better to open a new question in order to share with other SO members.

Comment: Sure, Just added https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63050010/single-button-in-dt-table

Comment: hi Stephane. Sorry my question was different. My bad. We can 2 button here. One expands all columns and another collapses single columns?. But can make a change so that collapse features collapses all columns at once?