# single button in DT table

Tags: r

With the below code, I get 2 button, "Show all" and "Show none". So just to check if its possible to have both features in single button.

```
datatable(
  iris, rownames = FALSE,
  extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = list(
      list(
        extend = 'colvis', 
        columns = c(2, 3, 4)
      ),
      list(
        extend = 'colvisGroup', 
        text = "Show all",
        show = ":hidden"
      ),
      list(
        extend = 'colvisGroup', 
        text = "Show none",
        hide = ":visible"
      )
    ),
    columnDefs = list(
      list(targets = c(2,3,4), visible = FALSE)
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
library(DT)

datatable(
  iris, rownames = FALSE,
  extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = list(
      list(
        extend = 'colvis', 
        columns = c(2, 3, 4)
      ),
      list(
        extend = 'columnToggle', 
        text = 'Toggle columns'
      )
    ),
    columnDefs = list(
      list(targets = c(2,3,4), visible = FALSE)
    )
  )
)
```